# python code for text file and mysql db search

Tags: python, database

I have a text file created and also a database written in mysql.My problem is,i only need the word from my textfile that exist in mysql database i have created.In other words,it has to parse through the database first and if that word exist in the text file i have,then it has to print that word also the nextword after the text file.
I need its python code,please help.

**Example**

Mysql database :car,house,pen,pencil,box

Text file : I have a car and a house

Output has to be : 'car and'

Comment: What have you tried so far? The output also seems illogical to me: “and” is not in the database, but you want it in the output? Why? This question may be too broad as it stands, and we won’t write all the code for interfacing with the database for you, I’m afraid.

Comment: i do apologize for my question,the 'and' in the text file is the next word after it finds the existing word in the database.that was my thought.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need:

```
mysql_row = "car,house,pen,pencil,box"
file_str = "I have a car and a house"

mysql_elements = mysql_row.split(",")
file_elements = file_str.split(" ")

output_array = []

for m_element in mysql_elements:
    for i in range(len(file_elements)):
        if ((m_element == file_elements[i]) and (i < len(file_elements)-1)):
           output_array.append(file_elements[i])
           output_array.append(file_elements[i+1])


print output_array
```